# How do I call different elements each time I use a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I'm assembling my site in a piecemeal fashion where I google search snippets of code and mechanical-turk my way to a solution. So apologies in advance if I am not asking the right question.

I have the first entry in my site working the way I want it to work. On click the divs slide left and reveal the content. Typically at this point I would just copy and paste my jQuery for each entry and change the values for the elements that are called. Instead I'd like to do it the "right" way. How would I get my script to fetch the elements that are required to move then move just them?

A 'keyword' that I can google and study up on may be all that I need to get on track. Here's what I put together...

[Live Demo of the Script](http://www.inbuildwetrust.com/test)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sVita').click(function() {
            $('#sVita').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "-150%" 
            });
            $('.secondView').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "5%" 
            });
            $('.invisibleBackButton').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "0"
            });         
        });

        $('.invisibleBackButton').click(function() {
            $('#sVita').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "-250px"
            });
            $('.secondView').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "+150%" 
            }); 
            $('.invisibleBackButton').animate({
                'marginLeft' : "-100%"
            });                     
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say give all of your elements a class, for example class="animateMe"

then in your doc ready function

```
$(".animateMe").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-150%" 
        });
        $(this).siblings('.secondView').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "5%" 
        });
        $(this).siblings('.invisibleBackButton').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "0"
        });         
    });
```

Comment: So doing it this way does it use the child of the div that is clicked to initiate the action? I'm trying to avoid having it click then every single entry (psvita, google glass, kraken) sliding open.

Comment: @piechart this will dynamically find the secondView within the row that you have clicked. so when you click each particular element it will search for the secondView and invisibleBackButton within your row. I updated this code because I was using "find" which looks at child elements, but your elements are siblings.

Comment: Awesome, ok so just so I understand the "siblings" is the part that says, "hey use the children of the div"? The "this" means THESE siblings? As a thought lets say I wrote... 

$(.awesomePants).siblings instead, it would use the siblings of the class awesomePants?

Comment: @piechart Yes. So if you look at it this way, I have several elements with the class "awesomePants". I create a click handler that says $(".awesomePants").click(function(){//code here}); within this click function I get a reference to "this" this refers to the element that was clicked on. so now that we have a reference to whatever you clicked, you can turn it blue or remove it. or in this case, find its siblings within the row and animate them.

Comment: Now i'm starting to implement what you suggested I'm beginning to understand a bit better.

".animateMe" is the class indentifier. Anything with that class will use the function. So I in turn created a second class called ".animateMeBack". On click of the invisible back button it slides back but i'm getting an odd side effect. Wondering if maybe it's my div hierarchy structure? I'll upload it now.

EDIT: Okay I understand what the issue is, quickly trying to fix it. standby

Comment: @piechart if you remember in your previous click function you refer to ".invisibleBackButton" so if you are clicking it and then referring to it again with a different class you might have some issues. I would recommend creating your function for the ".invisibleBackButton" instead of ".animateMeBack"

Comment: SUCCESSSS!! Okay so first I copied and pasted what you wrote for me and tried to make a back function. But it was all wonky. Then I realized that the first line is acting on whatever div we are placing the class upon so I created a graphic wrapper for my graphics and then called the third line to animate that wrapper. 

Can you please take a look at the site and tell me if it's good or bad architecturally? This was such a huge help. Thank you xBillion

Comment: if I may ask, how would I go about flagging that one is "open" so if I open another entry it closes the other?

Comment: @piechart you could create a variable to store the open div. and then on click you could trigger the function for invisible back button.

var selectedDiv;
$(".animateMe").click(function() {
       if(selectedDiv)
     $(selectedDiv).siblings(".invisibleBackButton").trigger("click");
        selectedDiv = this;
        $(this).animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-150%" 
        });
        $(this).siblings('.secondView').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "5%" 
        });
        $(this).siblings('.invisibleBackButton').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "0"
        });         
    });

Comment: ok I think i understand what you're saying. I'll noodle around with it. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @piechart sure thing. you could do the same type of behavior if you add another class as well and you could check for its presence. for example after you animate it you could say $(this).addClass("open"); then before adding the class open you could say if($(".open").length)$(".open").siblings(".invisibleBackButton").trigger("click");  $(".open").removeClass("open"); $(this).addClass("open")

Comment: This second method you are describing, is it changing the div "animateMe" to "open"? So then the if is detecting if there is a class called "open" and if so animating it out and changing the div class back to whatever it was before? 

I'm confused at how it knows to close the PSVITA entry if I am clicking the GLASS entry?

Comment: @piechart no, you would be adding an additional class. The logic in plain text would be that on page load nothing is open, aka nothing has the class "open". you click on something, all of the animations happen and then the thing that has opened gets the class "open". The next time you click something you want to say "hey, before we open this guy, is anyone open? oh yea, there is a div with the open class. lets close him, then remove the open class." after this is done, we continue our next open animation and when it finishes we add the class open to the div.

Comment: @piechart here is a quick demo I made for you with jsfiddle, its basic but it demonstrates the idea http://jsfiddle.net/Lv1jwkkd/